# Searching through and matching words in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file in which I have words like `SOP, OP, GOP, TOP`. I want to match case where only `'OP'` is picked up and nothing else. However my code is printing everything that matches OP (it prints SOP, GOP, TOP as well)

```
def method(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as infile:
        csvfile = csv.reader(infile)
        for i in csvfile:
            if "OP" in i[2]:
               print(i[0])
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: show the fragment of the input file contents

Comment: if "OP" == i[2] <--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if "OP" in i[2]` searches the substring in your cell.

Perform strict equality:

```
if "OP" == i[2]:
```

or test if `"OP"` is present anywhere in the row:

```
if "OP" in i:
```

Answer (score 1):

use the == operator instead of the in operator.

```
if i[2] == 'OP':
    print(i[0])
```